# understanding ast.literal_eval in the code

Tags: python-2.7, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to follow [this documentation for same region replication](http://s3.%20https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/content-replication-using-aws-lambda-and-amazon-s3/).

I have this line in the code so just trying to understand what it does mean?

```
sns_message = ast.literal_eval(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
```

What does `ast.literal_eval` do here?

```
key = str(urllib.unquote_plus(sns_message['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']).decode('utf8'))
```

Trying to understand urllib.unquote_plus here as to why it is used?

Answer (score 2):

ast.literal_eval converts the value type to the one based on it's format. The below code will convert the string to list based on it's format.

```
string_a = "['test', 'example']"
list_a = ast.literal_eval(string_a)
```

If you check the type of string_a and list_a, you can see that string_a type will be string and that of list_a will be list.

Also the function urllib.unquote_plus will remove the '+' signs from url's and replaces it with spaces.

```
>>> s = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/?q1=xx+xx+xx'
>>> urllib.unquote_plus(s)
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/?q1=xx xx xx'
```